# InAppBrowser using Cordova 3.5.0

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, inappbrowser

I am using InAppBrowser with Cordova 3.5.0 and when I run my app it opens the child browser but the close button on the upper right corner on Android does not work... so I am not able to return to the app at all... any help would be appreciated:

I have properly added the plugin to my project by issuing this:

Here´s the code I am using:

cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.mywebsite.com', '_blank', 'location=yes', 'closebuttoncaption=close');">Open Page</a>
```

What am I missing?!!

Thank you...

Comment: Your code is correct. Could be an error at a later time that is blocking any further execution. Can you post your console log from the moment you trigger `window.open`?

Answer (score 1):

You have too many single quotes around the options. The options are not separated individually by them but just by a comma rather.

so

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.mywebsite.com', '_blank', 'location=yes, closebuttoncaption=close');">Open Page</a>
```